# The current user is not a tenant-administrator

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I have owner right of a teamsite. But I am no tenant administrator. I only want access with PowerShell to my own teamsite not to the whole farm. But I found this code below to logon to sharepoint-online with administrative-rights.

```
$username = "my email-address"
$password = "my password"
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userName, $(convertto-securestring $Password -asplaintext -force)
Connect-SPOService -Url https://mydomain-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential $cred
```

Running the code leads to an error saying that I am not a tenant-administrator.
Is it possible to connect to just the teamsite and not the whole farm?

Gr, Peter

Comment: replace the url with your team site url....you URL is tenant Admin url.

Comment: I did. But then I get the error: current site is not a tenant administration site

Comment: that would be a no; first because you use would not have permissions over the cmdlet [-Identity].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannt use the Connect-SPOService rather use the PNP or use the below [PowerShell CSOM](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/af9c7b19-c1fa-4637-bfa8-4a840aa0388f/connecting-to-sharepoint-online-using-powershell-without-tenant-admin-name-and-password).

```
#Import the required DLL
Import-Module 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
#OR
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'

#Mysite URL
$site = 'https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename'

#Admin User Principal Name
$admin = 'yourusername@tenant.onmicrosoft.com'

#Get Password as secure String
$password = Read-Host 'Enter Password' -AsSecureString

#Get the Client Context and Bind the Site Collection
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($site)

#Authenticate
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($admin , $password)
$context.Credentials = $credentials

$list = $context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle('PowerShell CSOM')
$context.Load($list)
$list.Description = "CSOM PowerShell - Did it!!!"
$list.Update()
$context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: CSOM is no option ( I am not authorized) . Is it perhaps possible to logon with PNP and use code From the Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell module?

Comment: Pnp has more commands related to client side.i would recommend either go pnp or csom

Comment: I already use pnp. But I have code that uses the Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShel module. And I want to try this code.

Comment: Spo commands always run under tenant admin rights so that is road block for you.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:** Realized its SPOService. You might want to make use of

> Connect-PnPOnline

You can pass site collection in this

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/connect-pnponline?view=sharepoint-ps

Comment: I did. But then I get the error: current site is not a tenant administration site

Comment: I don't want to user connect-pnponline. I want to use the Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell module

Comment: Sorry, you will have to use CSOM